# Area enclosed by polar curves

Tags: polar-coordinates, area

Given $$r_1(\theta)=2(1+\cos\theta) \\ r_2(\theta)=2(1-\cos\theta)$$ I want to find the area of the region resulting from the intersection of those curves. Is the following integral correct?

$$
2A= \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} [r_2(\theta)]^2 ,\ d\theta + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} [r_1(\theta)]^2 \, d\theta
$$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179453/area-bounded-by-polar-curves?rq=1)

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, isn't that the symmetric difference?

Answer (score 0):

HINT....If you consider the graphs of the functions, the area enclosed by both of them is, by symmetry, $$4\times \frac 12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}4(1-\cos\theta)^2d\theta$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Yes, I can finish it. Anyway, I want to learn how to build the right integral without considering symmetries or other geometric tricks. I need to learn the entireanalytic process.

Comment: But in order to establish the limits you really need a picture

Comment: Yes, I need the picture to find out how to build the integral. But I want to avoid to assume the symmetries of the graph.

Comment: These graphs are reflections of each other in the y axis, so it makes sense to take advantage of the symmetry in this example

Comment: I understand, David. But I choose this curves just as an example. The essence of my doubt stay in a more general, but similar cases. In those, the curves could be not reflections and I wouldn't know how to proceed. That's why I want to avoid geometric arguments, because in most cases they can't be applied.

Comment: OK. In more general situations you still need a diagram, and usually you need to find the $\theta$ values at points where the curves meet, decide which curve is inside and which is outside, and also find the tangents at the origin, i.e. the values of $\theta$ when $r=0$